# LaTeX: Prevent line break in a span of text

Tags: latex

How can I prevent LaTeX from inserting linebreaks in my `\texttt{...}` or `\url{...}` text regions?  There's no spaces inside I can replace with `~`, it's just breaking on symbols.

**Update**: I don't want to cause line overflows, I'd just rather LaTeX insert linebreaks before these regions rather than inside them.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

`\mbox` is the simplest answer. Regarding the update:

TeX prefers overlong lines to adding too much space between words on a line; I think the idea is that you will notice the lines that extend into the margin (and the black boxes it inserts after such lines), and will have a chance to revise the contents, whereas if there was too much space, you might not notice it.

Use [`\sloppy`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=overfull) or `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}` to adjust this behavior, at least a little. Another possibility is [`\raggedright`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ragright) (or `\begin{raggedright}...\end{raggedright}`).

Answer (score 104):

Surround it with an `\mbox{}`

Comment: Will this encourage LaTeX to insert a linebreak before the region if it would overflow the line?

Comment: No.  The `\nohyphens{}` command, found in the `hypenat` package, just might.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried \nohyphens{\url{...}}, and it still allows linebreaks.

Answer (score 40):

Also, if you have two subsequent words in regular text and you want to avoid a line break between them, you can use the ~ character.

For example:

```
As we can see in Fig.~\ref{BlaBla}, there is nothing interesting to see. A~better place..
```

This can ensure that you don't have a line starting with a figure number (without the Fig. part) or with an uppercase A.

Comment: Just to note that `~` is a non-breaking _space_ character, that is, it also inserts a space (sometimes one may want to prevent breaking without inserting a space).

Answer (score 31):

Use \nolinebreak

> \nolinebreak[number]
>
> The \nolinebreak command prevents LaTeX from
> breaking the current line at the point of the command. With the
> optional argument, number, you can convert the \nolinebreak command
> from a demand to a request. The number must be a number from 0 to 4.
> The higher the number, the more insistent the request is.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20180424131455/http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm#nolinebreak

Answer (score 18):

Define myurl command:

```
\def\myurl{\hfil\penalty 100 \hfilneg \hbox}

I don't want to cause line overflows, 
I'd just rather LaTeX insert linebreaks before 
\myurl{\tt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012799/} 
regions rather than inside them.
```