# Non-breakable expression without overflow

Tags: latex

How to insert in a paragraph an expression that won't be cut by a new line, and that won't overflow in the margin either?

I would like the expression to try staying on the same line, but to go on the next one if there is not enough space (rather than overflowing).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [expression that won't break no matter what] consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{document}
```

I checked [LaTeX: Prevent line break in a span of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012799/latex-prevent-line-break-in-a-span-of-text) but `\mbox` makes an overflow in the margin, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29257/how-to-prevent-latex-from-line-breaking-a-phrase also does. I also tried `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}`, but it always makes a new line, even when not necessary.

This would be an equivalent to CSS' `inline-block` I guess.

Comment: "won't break no matter what" is different from "try staying on the same line, but [break if necessary]". It would be best if you can provide something that the community can use to replicate your issue via a minimal working example (MWE). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Are you okay with manually breaking the too-long in-line equation?

Comment: What I mean is that I don't want a new line to come in the middle of the expression. I accept a new line before the expression, but only if it is required to avoid an overflow. Ok, I'm preparing a MWE.